# jquery custom validation error in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using jQuery validation plugin. When I use custom validation and ad ajax for some validation it always return same result whether I enter wrong or correct input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var response;
            var email;
            if ($("#email").val() != '')
                email = $("#email").val();
            //<!-- add vlidator -->
            $.validator.addMethod(
             "varify_user", function (value, element) {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "welcome/verify_user",
                     type: "POST",
                     data: "{ password: '" + value + "',email: '" + email + "' }",
                     async: false,
                     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                     success: function (json) {
                         response = json.success;
                     },
                     dataType: 'json'
                 });
                 return response;
             },
              "email or password is incorrect"
             );
            jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.varify_user = { varify_user: true };
 $("#signIn_form").validate({
 submitHandler: function (form) {

                    $('#register-form').submit();
                }
            });

        });   
    </script>
```

and my code in razor view is

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="email">
           <em>* </em> Email: </label>
           <label> <input type="text" id="email" 
                 name="email" class="required email" /></label>                  

        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for = "password">
            <em>*</em>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" 
                    name="password" class="required varify_user" />
        </div>
```

I'm devloping jQuery Mobile app please help me.

Comment: What exactly is not working, be more specific

Comment: @Austin bro i m getting error in custom validation i have created add class varify_user which always return false wether i enter correct or wrong input

Comment: You spelled verify wrong in a couple places. Also "if ($("#email").val() != '')
                email = $("#email").val()" should be a "!=="

Comment: I wasn't giving an answer just commenting on style